# Php -> operator

Tags: php, class, operators

Can anyone tell me what the -> operator would be accessing/calling? in this context:

```
$query = db_select('date_formats', 'd')->extend('PagerDefault');
```

Is it assigning a class of PagerDefault to &query or accessing property or nested function or something? I'm just completely guessing. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It executes the method `extend` on the object returned by `db_select`. For details on objects and an introduction, refer to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

Comment: So why is 'pagerDefault' being passed as an argument? or is 'pagerDefault' and the object 'db_select' returns both being passed to 'extend'?

Comment: @Exceii `'pagerDefault'` is the argument to the method `extend`. You could also write this code as: `$tmp = db_select('date_formats', 'd'); $tmp->extend('PagerDefault');`. The object is implicitely passed along with the arguments. You should really read the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) or the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) on object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 2):

You can also write it like this:

```
$query = db_select('date_formats', 'd');
$query->extend('PagerDefault');
```

First line assigns to `$query` an object that is returned by `db_select()`, the second one calls `extend()` method on this object.

Answer (score 0):

It calls the `extend` method of the Drupal query object, in this case it's extending the query by adding paging functionality.